# Accessing controls from specific master page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, content-pages

I have 2 master pages (Normal and Admin), these master pages are being appended to the page at run-time, based on the user authentication, now i want to access the control of the master page, i have a table control in both of the master pages, now i want to access the control from content page.

I am unable to get the logic how to setup the path of the master page and access the control from that master page in content page.

Does anyone have any idea how i could go about it

---

**Updated Question**

I have a product listing on the content page, wherein i have some product listing under update-panel, whenever user add product to the cart, i want to update the asp:Table which is inside master-page, now because the add button is under update-panel, i am unable to set the content to the table inside master-page.

Is there any work around to show the products added to the cart.

Comment: Some code will be help to get a good answer. The general idea is to use the FindControl().

Comment: hi @Aristos, can you have a look at my question, i have updated it